# How to copy date format as is when using "Get Value" formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My problem is that **dates** are not being copied in the right format indicated when using "call cell formula" (I'm not sure what it's called) or "get value of cell",

so to see my sample, here's a screenshot:

[image]

In this screenshot, `July 7, 2020` should be copied as is in place of `44019`

It's like it's being calculated instead of being copied as is. I have already changed the format on `Date` settings, but it's not following it if there are other text in the formula together with it.

If I use a simple `(D2)` it will copy it correctly, but not for this one and I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `&D2&` you could use:

```
&TEXT(D2,"mmmm, d, yyyy")&
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is simply amazing. I didn't know (yet) that it's possible. But new doors are unlocked today for me. Thank you.